# Why isn't my object storing into an array each time I read a line of a file? Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I'm reading data in from a text file. Each line has a year at the beginning of the line followed by some data for each month. I'm trying to save both the year and month data into an object and storing it into an object array for each line I read. I'm pretty sure I've done everything right apart from my parseFile method. Here it is -

```
          while ((line1 = word_reader.readLine()) != null) {
              int year;
              double[] monthlyRain = new double[12];
              String[] values1 = line1.split(",");
              // validation
              if (values1.length == 13){
                  year = Integer.parseInt(values1[0]);

                  for (int i = 1; i < values1.length; i++) { // Start from 1.
                        monthlyRain[i - 1] = Double.parseDouble(values1[i]);
                  }

                  int i =0;
                  rainfallYears[i] = new RainfallYear(year,monthlyRain);
                  i++;
              }
          }
```

I thought the lines towards the bottom after the for loop would work but it isn't.

Comment: Do not delete the content of your questions. That is not how this site works. Read its documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you place your object always at index 0:

```
int i =0;
rainfallYears[i] = new RainfallYear(year,monthlyRain);
```

put `i` outside the `while-loop.`:

```
int i = 0;
while ((line1 = word_reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

then it should work.